# FancyBox height incorrect when iframe contents rendered with ejs

Tags: jquery, express, fancybox, ejs

This is odd.  Fancybox is performing an iFrame request to a page on my site (NOTE: this page does has javascript that fetches extra content to add to the page).  When this page is served to FancyBox via Express.js as a static route the FancyBox iFrame autosizes perfectly.  However, when that exact same page is served up using ejs the Fancybox has a height of approx. 200px and a long scroll bar.

FancyBox implementation:

```
$('#results').on('click', '.items', function() {
            $(".post").fancybox({
                type: 'iframe',
                minWidth: '90%',
                maxHeight: '95%',
                autoResize: true,
                autoSize: true,
                autoCenter: true,
            });
        });
```

Static route to html file works fine.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/post'));
```

Sending the same HTML to FancyBox using ejs to render the template looks wacky.. Ideas?

```
app.get('/post', function(req, res) {
    res.render('post.ejs', {

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.  This issue was caused by some slightly different code within an angular controller.  Has nothing to do with how express was serving the file. durp.